# Dictionary comprehension on a filter object

Tags: python, dictionary

What's going on with my dictionary comprehension here?

I am parsing a BLAST file and want to create objects for each line in the file. Ideally each object will be stored in a dictionary for use later in the program. 
Parsing works fine but I end up with a blank transSwiss dictionary.

Here are a few lines of output as an example:

```
c0_g1_i1|m.1    gi|74665200|sp|Q9HGP0.1|PVG4_SCHPO  100.00  372 0   0   1   372 1   372 0.0   754
c1000_g1_i1|m.799   gi|48474761|sp|O94288.1|NOC3_SCHPO  100.00  747 0   0   5   751 1   747 0.0  1506
c1001_g1_i1|m.800   gi|259016383|sp|O42919.3|RT26A_SCHPO    100.00  268 0   0   1   268 1   268 0.0   557
c1002_g1_i1|m.801   gi|1723464|sp|Q10302.1|YD49_SCHPO   100.00  646 0   0   1   646 1   646 0.0  1310
```

I'm trying to make each BLAST line a parse_blast object.

```
class parse_blast(object):

    def __init__(self, line):

        #Strip end-of-line and split on tabs
        self.fields = line.strip("\n").split("\t")
        self.transcriptId, self.isoform = self.fields[0].split("|")
        self.swissStuff = self.fields[1].split("|")
        self.swissProtId = self.swissStuff[3]
        self.percentId = self.fields[2]

    def filterblast(self):
        return float(self.percentId) > 95



blastmap = map(parse_blast, blast_output.readlines())

filtered = filter(parse_blast.filterblast, blastmap)

transSwiss = {blastmap.transcriptId:blastmap for blastmap.transcriptId in filtered}
```

Comment: As a guess, your `percentId` is a string, not an `int`. You don't really need to use a class here at all, it makes this fairly confusing. As pointed out, you're also attempting to overwrite the local variable in your dict comprehension, too.

Comment: Correct, percentId is a string. Also, this isn't my entire program, just the parts I'm having trouble with currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
for blastmap.transcriptId in filtered
```

you're trying to assign each element of `filtered` to `blastmap.transcriptId` in sequence. `blastmap` is either a list or an instance of the `map` type, depending on your Python version, so it has no `transcriptId` attribute, and your code fails with an `AttributeError`.

Use a variable. A *new* variable:

```
transSwiss = {pb.transcriptId: pb for pb in filtered}
```

Comment: Oh interesting, thank you.  So this seems like where the new objects are actually being created (instanced?) in Python 3?